# In Linux how to make a file with a name that is current date and time

Tags: linux

I want to make a file which name will be a current date and time. I can create a file with the `touch` command. Also I can get current time with the `date` command. So, I think, I need to somehow pipe the second command to the first one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the return value from a shell expression as the argument to `touch`:

```
touch $( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' )
```

Result: A file named e.g. `2012-03-11_14-33-53`.

This answer assumes you're using `bash` (it's described in the `man` page section *Command Substitution*), but other shells will work the same or only slightly different.

Comment: @MdGao And described in the same section of the man page. [I prefer the answer I gave though, here are a few reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: I removed my comment because Markdown broken the backticks. thanks for the link @DanielBeck

Comment: You can escape \`backticks\` using backslashes: `\\``

Comment: what if i want to make a file with a name of exact output of `date` command? If I do `touch $(date)`, it creates multiple files with parts of the date output. Is it possible to add quotes or do anything else, so `touch` will create only 1 file?

Comment: @gasan Just surround it with `"` quotation marks. You can imagine the output of `date` replacing that part of the command line, and `touch Sun Mar 11 14:48:31 CET 2012` would create files name `Sun`, `Mar`, etc. `touch "Sun Mar 11 14:48:31 CET 2012"` on the other hand works fine (except I'm not sure how good the colons will work).

Comment: @Daniel, thanks a lot, double quotes worked (single didn't).

Comment: @gasan Single quotes won't work because they don't allow command substitution or any other interpretation. See [quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting) in the Bash manual.

Comment: @gasan The difference is that content of single quotes isn't evaluated. Try it with `echo "$HOME"` and `echo '$HOME'`. That's why I suggested use of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more simple command

```
touch $(date | tr ' ' '-')
```

Comment: Somewhat less elegant and arguably less portable, but, yeah, that’ll work too.

Comment: OK, since I know you’re reading this, I’ll go into a little more detail: Daniel’s answer gives a result in a known and totally controlled format.  (1) The output from `date` typically shows the time as hh:mm:ss.  Your answer results in filenames containing colons.  This could cause an error on Windows-based file systems. (2) The raw output from a simple invocation of `date` is locale-dependent; i.e., customized to the local language.  Try `LANG=de_DE date` and `LANG=fr_FR date` to see examples. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2a) Therefore, in the (unlikely?) event that you ever change the language on your system, or you give your script *and a collection of data files from your system* to somebody whose system is configured for a different language, there will be a mismatch. (I’m not sure that this would be a real problem, but it would be an aesthetic issue.) (2b) I don’t know of any locale that does this, but there could theoretically be a locale where `date` writes the date as mm/dd/yy (or dd/mm/yy). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you ever encountered such a system, you would have filenames containing slashes, and that will cause errors.  (3) Daniel’s answer gives a result where lexicographical (i.e., alphabetical) order, as produced by ``ls`` or ``*``, corresponds to chronological order.  With your answer, all the `Fri` files will be at the beginning of any lexicographically sorted list, and ``Apr`` and ``Aug`` will appear before all the other months.